# How do I fix sticking/tight hydraulic brake calipers?

Tags: brakes, disc-brake

I took my wheel off my front forks to repair a puncture.  I had the bike upside down when I removed the wheel.  When I came to replace the wheel back into the fork slots, the hydraulic disk calipers were too tight to accept the brake disc. I had to use something to prize open the calipers so the gap was wide enough.  When I span the wheel it's still to tight and the calipers still make contact with the disc. Is there any reason why the calipers are now tighter and how do I fix the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I also had the same problem. I tried everything but had no luck! I even tried to pry the piston back with a screwdriver! It turned out that somehow the brake it self was tweaked. I loosened the mount screws (where it mounts to the frame or fork) and I actually saw it shift back to it's proper position! Hope this helps!

Comment: You had your bike upside down?! See [rule 49](http://www.velominati.com/the-rules/#49)!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, while you had the wheel out, the brake lever was pulled, and the piston position was reset too close to the disc.

You need to remove the brake pads, and very gently push the pistons all the way back into the caliper.

Then replace the wheel, and pump the brake lever. It should take 2 or 3 pumps to feel normal again.

Hope that helps.

Comment: A caliper spacer/ bleed block should have come with your brakes. If you have one of these once you have the brakes partly open force this (essentially a thin wedge) in. You should always put something in between the pads if the wheels are out. Many rides have been ruined while the cars in the back of the car!

Answer (score 1):

Try watching this video.  I did this on my bike and it worked for me.

Comment: While this video certainly helps, its generally preferred that you add a summary to your answer, and leave external links as supporting information.  While its unlikely youtube goes away, its not impossible, and that would leave this answer as an empty link.  Please also take a moment to read the [tour] to see how StackExchange is organised.